# Event register page style bug

Tags: civievent, issues

I'm using 4.7.29 CiviCRM with latest Wordpress version.

On my event register page, I've an issue with scroll menu (set with Price set option) :
[image: CiviCRM event bug]

The option is cut. And it is also when I select an other in the listing.

Can I resolve it myself or it's a general bug ?
I've already try severals browser.

Thank you !

Comment: best if you can compare with the civicrm demo sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've modify this css line to solve the problem :

```
    .select2-container .select2-choice > .select2-chosen {
    line-height: 15px;
    }
```